# What is the proper format for a wallet-cli transfer since 0.11.0.0?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I'm trying to send to Shapeshift while stating priority and ring size. I'm either getting `Error: failed to parse address` or `Error: payment id has invalid format`. I'm using `[]` around the priority, ring size, and payment ID, as the example on wallet-cli shows. I'm also copying the address and payment ID straight from Shapeshift. I'm getting these problems without the `[]` as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [] characters are not meant to represent actual [ and ] characters to type. They are normally used to denote optional parameters, though this not always the case.

If you wanted to send a normal priority transaction for 10 monero to address 4blah with ring size 5 and payment id 1234, then you would use:

transfer normal 5 4blah 10 1234

The real payment ID should be 256 bits (64 hexadecimal characters). If you see one that's only 64 bits (16 hexadecimal characters), it's not meant to be used manually, and should be used as part of an integrated address.

Comment: Ok, that brought me to a double spend error. I think the gui-wallet is messing some things up here.

Comment: I was also putting in a mixin count where that word "normal" should be.

Comment: Double spend can happen if the wallet crashes after sending, etc, or if you use the wallet file from two programs at the same time. Did this happen ? Anyway, you can run "rescan_spent" in the wallet, or there should be a button for this somewhere in the GUI.

Comment: There's a `Rescan wallet balance` button on the `Settings` page of the GUI.